# How to generate Dynamic href?

Tags: javascript, html

I would like to generate dynamic href link using javascript or HTML for something like this

```
<a target="_self" href="detail.aspx?videoID={@ID}">
    <img src="{@AlternateThumbnailUrl}" alt="{@Title}" width="400" />
</a>
```

Comment: Plesse provide more information. Eg, are you only using JS and HTML? Provide more code and tell us how such a dynamic link would get generated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you can build an href with string concatenation in javascript. I don't know what kind of parameters you are attempting to pass without a more concrete example

```
var example = "ww.google.com";
var exampleHref = "http://" + google;
```

Then you can create a new DOM node with this href attribute

```
// get some parent div with id
var div = document.getElementById('someDiv');

// create <a> tag
var tag = document.createElement(a);

// set the href attribute
tag.setAttribute('href', exampleHref);

// append the node to the parent
div.appendChild(tag);
```

So given the extra information, you can write a JavaScript function to create the strings required then take the result from this and create the required DOM nodes.

takes the parent node where you want to insert it, then the params     given above

```
function insertDOM(parentNode, id, altUrl, title) {

    // create <a> tag and <img> tag
    var aTag = document.createElement(a);
    var imgTag = document.createElement(img);

    // set the appropriate properties
    aTag.setAttribute(href, id);
    aTag.setAttribute(target,'_self');

    imgTag.setAttribute(src, altUrl);
    imgTag.setAttribute(alt, alt);
    imgTag.setAttribute(width, 400);

    // attach the img tag to a, then a to the parent
    aTag.appendChild(imgTag);
    parentNode.appendChild(aTag);
}
```

and you would call it like so:

```
// get parent node
var div = document.getElementById('something');
insertDOM(div, id, altUrl, title);
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing, its useful.. :)